# Where to post a Fluid Power Systems/Mechatronic Engineering question

Tags: discussion

Which StackExchange forum would be the best to post on? There doesn't seem to be a general Engineering forum and most of the Engineering forums that are there are [closed].

Comment: This should be in meta, FYI.

Comment: Thanks Shamtam, I'll post it there.  I'm posting a question about where to post lol.. Ahh life is good.

Answer (score 4):

Normally I wouldn't mention an Area 51 proposal because the definition / committment phases can take many months and many fail to get enough interest, but [Engineering](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60453/engineering) has reached 100% committment  in the past few days so should only be a few weeks from going into private beta, so now would be a good time to commit so you can fire away with your quesion(s) and see how it goes.

Other than that out of the live sites maybe [Robotics.SE](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/) would be OK depending on the nature of your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot PeterJ : ]